# Reindex and delete in sequence on Elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I will need to reindex, delete the old index and rename to the name from the old deleted index, it will execute in a random ordem in NodeJS, trying to delete and rename values doesn't exist.

I did try to run with promises without success and using .then(function(resp) and the same problem happens.

```
es.reindex({
    refresh: true,
    body: {
        "source": {
            "index": current_index
        },
        "dest": {
            "index": current_index + ".tmp"
        }
    }
});
es.indices.delete({
    index: current_index,
    ignore: [404]
}, function(err, resp, respcode) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error deleting index " + current_index);
        console.log("   Error: " + err);
        console.log("   Resp code: " + respcode);
    }
});
es.reindex({
    refresh: true,
    body: {
        "source": {
            "index": current_index + ".tmp"
        },
        "dest": {
            "index": current_index
        }
    }
});
es.indices.delete({
    index: current_index + ".tmp",
    ignore: [404]
}, function(err, resp, respcode) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error deleting index " + current_index);
        console.log("   Error: " + err);
        console.log("   Resp code: " + respcode);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the right way of doing it:

```
const {reindex1Body} = await es.reindex({
    refresh: true,
    body: {
        "source": {
            "index": current_index
        },
        "dest": {
            "index": current_index + ".tmp"
        }
    }
});

try {
    await es.indices.delete({
        index: current_index
    }, {
        ignore: [404]
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.log("Error deleting index " + current_index);
    console.log("   Error: " + err);
    console.log("   Resp code: " + err.statusCode);
}

const {reindex2Body} = await es.reindex({
    refresh: true,
    body: {
        "source": {
            "index": current_index + ".tmp"
        },
        "dest": {
            "index": current_index
        }
    }
});

try {
    await es.indices.delete({
        index: current_index + ".tmp"
    }, {
        ignore: [404]
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.log("Error deleting index " + current_index);
    console.log("   Error: " + err);
    console.log("   Resp code: " + err.statusCode);
}
```